# Название Swing компонента по картинке

Tags: java, swing

Хочу использовать такой же Swing-компонент, как на картинке, но я не знаю название класса.

**Какой Swing компонент на картинке?**
(Надо название класса)

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это `JTabbedPane`

Посмотрите:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html